# If I have a Python list of CSV files, how do I merge them all into one giant CSV file?

Tags: python, list, file, csv

I created a list of files like this:

```
merge_files = []
for i in range(2, 12):
    merge_files.append(pandas.read_csv(final_user_study_path + "/P" + str(i) + "/DataCollection/data/merge.csv"))
```

I want to create a giant `csv` file with all the files from this list.

Is this the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: Using Python for this is probably overkill when it's trivial to do this using the shell

Comment: @matthewDaly is right.. just cat them together.

Comment: While it is true that Python can be overkill for this, you can quickly build in logic in Python to exclude certain paths, walk over certain subpaths and do filtering and so on. It is not clear if OP is going to use this one time or multiple.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend unix shell. If they have no headers, or only first have a header:

```
cat file1.csv file2.csv ... fileN.csv > result.csv
```

If they have headers, you have to cut them off first:

```
cat file1.csv > result.csv
for i in {1..N}; do tail +2 file$i.csv >> result.csv; done
```

If files are in different directories - use path to each file:

```
cat path1/file.csv path2/file.csv > result.csv
```

Comment: Can I still do this if they're in different directories with the same file name?

Answer (score 0):

The pandas way would be to use concat on the dataframes, this can be useful if you want to do some operations too (as filtering, removing duplicates... etc)

```
import io
import pandas as pd
```

Let's create two files

```
csv1 = "a,b\n1,2"
csv2 = "a,b\n3,4"

file1 = io.StringIO(csv1)
file2 = io.StringIO(csv2)
```

Loop over them and concat:

```
pd.concat((pd.read_csv(i) for i in [file1,file2])).to_csv(index=False)
```

Results in:

```
'a,b\n1,2\n3,4\n'
```

---

Adapted for you in a readable way (my preferred way):

```
files = []
for i in range(2, 12):
    path = "{}/P{}/DataCollection/data/merge.csv".format(final_user_study_path,i)
    files.append(path)

pd.concat((pd.read_csv(i) for i in files)).to_csv("output.csv",index=False)
```